# Refactor C# unsafe method

Tags: c#, array, memory-management, pointers

I have the following two unsafe methods that I would like to refactor:

```
public static unsafe void UnsafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, short value)
{
    fixed (byte* numRef = &(array[pos]))
    {
        *((short*)numRef) = value;
    }
}

public static unsafe void UnsafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, int value)
{
    fixed (byte* numRef = &(array[pos]))
    {
        *((int*)numRef) = value;
    }
}
```

If I want to make the method managed will the following conversion be right ?

```
public static void UnsafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, short value)
{
    array[pos] = value;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't update a question with your solution. You're free to add this solution as an answer, though. (There's a link that explains this, but I cannot locate it right now.)

Comment: I think you should at least try compiling this conversion, before asking for review.

Comment: The link @BCdotWEB mentioned is here [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher Thanks. I searched for "should not do", should have searched for "may nor do". Bookmarked it now for future use.

Comment: @BCdotWEB you can find some autocomment here: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/frequently-posted-comments

Answer (score 6):

```
public static unsafe void UnsafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, short value)
{
    fixed (byte* numRef = &(array[pos]))
    {
        *((short*)numRef) = value;
    }
}
```

is not

```
public static void UnsafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, short value)
{
    array[pos] = value;
}
```

**Explanation:** 
`&(array[pos])` gets the address of the memory of the "pos"th element of the array and `byte* numRef = &(array[pos])` makes that the pointer `numRef` points to these address.
if you do `*numRef = value` you write `value` into the address `numRef` is pointing -- which is the "pos"th element of the array. 
But you lose precision, because value is `short` (2 Byte) but you write into a `byte` (1 Byte) address.

if you cast `numRef` -- which is a pointer to a `byte` (= ONE byte) -- into a `short` (= TWO byte) then the pointer points to the same address BUT the pointer is 2 Byte "wide". 
What i mean with "wide" is that if numRef points to 0x0 and you do `numRef++` then `numRef` will point to 0x2 because it is short and short is 2 Byte big.

We have this `short* numRef` and you want to do `*numRef = value` then you will write in the memory of the "pos"th element of the array AND in the "pos + 1"th element of the array. so this method is not:

```
array[pos] = value
```

it is something like (i can't say that exactly because i am not the compiler):

```
array[pos] = upperByte(value)
array[pos + 1] = lowerByte(value)
```

---

**Grafical Explanation:**

May this be your array:

```
Address in RAM| 0x02 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 0x05 | 0x06 | 0x07 | 0x08 | 0x09 |
Array Indexer | [0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  | [4]  | [5]  | [6]  | [7]  |
Content       | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
```

and pos is 2.
and value is this: `value = 0x1234`

so the pointer `numRef` points to 0x04:

```
print(numRef); // Ouptup will be 0x04
```

and looks like this:

```
Pointer byte* numRef      -->      <--
Address in RAM| 0x02 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 0x05 | 0x06 | 0x07 | 0x08 | 0x09 |
Array Indexer | [0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  | [4]  | [5]  | [6]  | [7]  |
Content       | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
```

and after *numRef = value the array looks like this:

```
Pointer byte* numRef      -->      <--
Address in RAM| 0x02 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 0x05 | 0x06 | 0x07 | 0x08 | 0x09 |
Array Indexer | [0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  | [4]  | [5]  | [6]  | [7]  |
Content       | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x34 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
```

---

if you cast it to short then you have this:

```
Pointer short* numRef     -->             <--
Address in RAM| 0x02 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 0x05 | 0x06 | 0x07 | 0x08 | 0x09 |
Array Indexer | [0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  | [4]  | [5]  | [6]  | [7]  |
Content       | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
```

and after *numRef = value the array looks like this:

```
Pointer short* numRef     -->             <--
Address in RAM| 0x02 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 0x05 | 0x06 | 0x07 | 0x08 | 0x09 |
Array Indexer | [0]  | [1]  | [2]  | [3]  | [4]  | [5]  | [6]  | [7]  |
Content       | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x12 | 0x34 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
```

---

**How it could be implemented (not recommended):**

> if you use this methods PLEASE test it. with different system (32 / 64
>   bit).

for the `public static unsafe void UnsafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, short value)`:

```
public static void SafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, short value)
{
    array[pos] = value >> 8;
    array[pos + 1] = value & 0xFF;
}
```

and for the same method with `int` (and here is the problem - is this int 64 or 32 bit?!) it could look like this:

```
// For 64 bit integer
public static void SafeMethod(byte[] array, int pos, int value)
{
    array[pos    ] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    array[pos + 1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    array[pos + 2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    array[pos + 3] = value & 0xFF;
}
```

Legend:

```
value >> x <=> shift the bits of value x times right
value << x <=> shift the bits of value x times left
value & 0xFF <=> value & 0b11111111 <=> logical bitwise and
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanation. So is it possible to convert that method to managed code?

Comment: well.. i don't know what the usecase of the Method is. Is this behavior of writing over more than one array element expected or a bug? if it is not a bug i would not recommend to programm it unmanaged, but you can do it. i will add it to my answer.

Comment: i meant i would not recommend to programm it managed .. :)

Comment: what about following, do you think it will behave the same?

`byte[] newBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);`
`Array.Copy(newBytes, 0, array, pos, newBytes.Length);`

Comment: that looks much better - try it